# Running Danger on Jenkins is skipped with the error: Not a Jenkins Pull Request

Tags: jenkins, github, danger

I want to run Danger test on the CI that runs on Jenkins. I'm using scripted pipelines.
I have installed the GitHub branch source plug-in into Jenkins. I have also created a personal access token to the `builds_user` account (that Jenkins uses for GitHub interaction), and stored this in the Jenkins credential store, with unique ID `builds_user_repos_acces￼`.

This is the way I'm running danger:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'builds_user_repos_access', passwordVariable: 'DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN', usernameVariable: '')]) {
   def dangerEnv = [
      "DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=${env.DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN}"
   ]
   stage('danger') {
      withEnv(buildEnv + dangerEnv) {
         sh 'bundle exec danger'
      }
   }
}
```

The `buildEnv` is a list of env variable that I need to run ruby gems. Everything works when I run other gems and when I run `bundle install`.

what I get is a warning:

> - bundle exec danger
>
> Not a Jenkins Pull Request - skipping 'danger' run.

I have also tried:

```
      stage('danger') {
         withEnv(buildEnv) {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'skbuilds_repos_access', passwordVariable: 'DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN', usernameVariable: '')]) {
               sh 'env'
               sh "bundle exec danger"
            }
         }
      }
```

And I can see that the DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN is there (masked).

Do you see what is wrong? Is there a way to get more info?

Answer (score 0):

Danger works only with pull request, so you have to make multibranch or github organization job in jenkins and connect jenkinsFile.

Comment: The Jenkins script where I added Danger runs on PR